# Check if item exists in Memcached, without pulling it?

Tags: php, memcached

I want to append data to an item in Memcached. But it seems that if the item does not exist, this action will not create an item and the data just would not be stored.
*talking php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a key exists in Memcache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091107/check-if-a-key-exists-in-memcache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use append.

If the item does not exist, you will get an error telling you that it didn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

To check correctly if an item exists in Memcached / PHP you should do:

```
$item = $m->get($key);
if ($m->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_SUCCESS) {
    // item exists ($item value)
} else {
    // item does not exist ($item is probably false)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If `Memcache::get()` returns false, the key doesn't exist (or an error occurred). Unlike `APC`, Memcache has no other functionality for verifying existence (or non-existence) of a key.

Comment: What about if the requested key holds `false` value?

Comment: After doing `$m->get(KEY)` you should use `$m->getResultCode() == Memcached::RES_SUCCESS` to check if `KEY` exists. Here is a list of possible result codes: http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php#114651